# PHP get object value

Tags: php

How to get the value of entityID? I tried var_dump(['entityID'); can't get the value.

```
SimpleSAML_Configuration Object
(
   [configuration:SimpleSAML_Configuration:private] => Array
    (
        [privatekey] => saml.pem
        [certificate] => saml.crt
        [entityID] => sample
        [idp] => sample
        [discoURL] => 
        [RelayState] => /
        [entityid] => sample
    )

  [location:SimpleSAML_Configuration:private] => authsources['default-sp']
  [filename:SimpleSAML_Configuration:private] => 
)
```

Comment: Your object probably provides some methods, so you can access the private properties.

Comment: It's private. You can't. If the class/object doesn't provide some getters you can use Reflection to set the acess level. Although this method is very brutal.

Comment: Try with  `get_object_vars($object)`

Comment: ok thanks for the replies @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason why the object's properties are private and the reason is exactly to prevent you accessing them as you want.

The `SimpleSAML_Configuration` class provides the method [`getValue()`](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/lib/SimpleSAML/Configuration.php#L394) to let you get the value of the key you need. If there is no value in the configuration, a default value (that you pass to `getValue()` as the second argument) is returned:

```
$config = SimpleSAML_Configuration::getInstance();
echo($config->getValue('entityID'));
```